# count() returns different results than get()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having an issue with

```
$query = $game->releases()->select(['created_at'])->unionAll(
    $game->seasons()->select(['created_at'])
);

foreach ($query->get() as $result) {
    echo $result->created_at.PHP_EOL;
}
dd($query->count('created_at'));
```

I can iterate over results and see there are 3 records, but when I aggregate count I can see that there are only 2, while I have 3 unique values.

```
2018-03-23 03:20:07
2018-03-24 03:20:07
2018-03-25 03:20:07
count: 2
```

**Why am I seeing different results in my count while my values are still unique?**

Comment: @ferbass `$query->count()` is performing a mysql `COUNT("created_at")` under the covers

Comment: thats weird. have you tried `count($query->get())`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out.  The issue is with my syntax in that the `count()` is happening on the first portion of the union, NOT the combined results.  In order for it to count all results, I had to take this approach:

```
$unionQuery = $game->releases()->select(['created_at'])->unionAll(
    $game->seasons()->select(['created_at'])
);

$records = DB::table(DB::raw("(".$unionQuery->toSql().") AS s"))
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) as updateCount')
    ->mergeBindings($unionQuery->getBaseQuery())
    ->first()->updateCount;
```